# Compute distance length between pixel values in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv

I need to create a difference image of two images and want to have the size/length of the difference of every pixel

I'm currently doing this:

```
cv::Mat diff = cv::abs(img1 - img2);
cv::Mat diffLen(diff.size(), CV_32FC1);
for(int x = 0; x < diff.size().width; ++x)
    for(int y = 0; y < diff.size().height; ++y)
    {
        float d = cv::norm(diff.at<Vec3f>(Point(x,y)));
        diffLen.at<float>(Point(x,y)) = d;
    }
```

Is there a more convenient way to do this?

Comment: How would you define the `size/length` between 2 pixels having values `R1, G1, B1` and `R2, G2. B2`

Comment: @ZDaR as the L2 Norm like in my Code now. It makes sense in my case.

Answer (score 2):

I was searching for a similar purpose, and here is what I've got now:

```
    cv::Mat diff = cv::abs(img1 - img2);
    diff = diff.mul(diff);
    cv::transform(diff, diff, cv::Mat::ones(1, diff.channels(), CV_32F));
    cv::sqrt(diff, diff);
```

It's not elegant. But seems that opencv doesn't provide "pixel-wise norm" operation.

Comment: I would move the `cv::transform()` above `diff.mul()` to avoid overflows e.g. with 8 bit images.

Answer (score 1):

May be you can use ParallelLoopBody :

```
class ParallelNorm : public ParallelLoopBody
{
private:
    Mat &diff;
    Mat &diffLen;

public:
    ParallelNorm(Mat& pDiff,Mat &result) :
        diff(pDiff),
        diffLen(result)
        {}
    virtual void operator()(const Range& range) const
    {

        for (int x = range.start; x < range.end; ++x)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < diffLen.rows; ++y)
            {
                float d = cv::norm(diff.at<Vec3f>(Point(x, y)));
                diffLen.at<float>(Point(x, y)) = d;
            }

        }
    }
};
```

and instead of your loop use

```
ParallelNorm x(diff,diffLen);
parallel_for_(Range(0,diff.cols),x);
```

In loop you can use pointer if you swap x and y...